# Present the data from one page to another page using cookies ,javascript and html

Tags: javascript, css, html, cookies

I have developed a **Page 1** and **Page 2** using Html and JavaScript. I'm trying to get the data from Page 1 and display it on Page 2 using **Cookies** and **JavaScript**. You can see the code below:

```
Page 1:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



<script>
function Submit(){
var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,20}$/;
//var emailRegex= /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
var ck_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i ;
var ck_username = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,20}$/;
var ck_password =  /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$/;

var fname=document.form.firstname.value,
    lname=document.form.lastname.value,
    femail=document.form.email.value,
    fuser=document.form.username.value,
    fpassword=document.form.password.value,
    fconpassword=document.form.confirmpassword.value,
    fmonth=document.form.birthday_month.value,
    fday=document.form.birthday_day.value,
    fyear=document.form.birthday_year.value;


if(fname == "")
{
document.form.firstname.focus();
document.getElementById("elmfirstnameError").innerHTML="Enter the First Name ";
return false;
}else if(!ck_name.test(fname)){
document.form.firstname.focus();
document.getElementById("elmfirstnameError").innerHTML=" Enter 3-20 character and no special charater";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmfirstnameError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(lname == "")
{
document.form.lastname.focus();
document.getElementById("elmlastnameError").innerHTML="Enter the Last Name ";
return false;
}else if(!ck_name.test(lname)){
document.form.lastname.focus();
document.getElementById("elmlastnameError").innerHTML="Enter 3-20 character and no special charater";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmlastnameError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(femail == "")
{
document.form.email.focus();
document.getElementById("elmemailError").innerHTML="Enter the Email Address";
return false;
}else if(!ck_email.test(femail)){
document.form.email.focus();
document.getElementById("elmemailError").innerHTML="You have entered an Invalid Email Address!";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmemailError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(fuser == "")
{
document.form.username.focus();
document.getElementById("elmeusernameError").innerHTML="Enter the Username";
return false;
}else if(!ck_username.test(fuser)){
document.form.username.focus();
document.getElementById("elmeusernameError").innerHTML="Enter the Username with 3-20 characters & no special charater";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmeusernameError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(fpassword == "")
{
document.form.password.focus();
document.getElementById("elmepasswordError").innerHTML="Enter the Password";
return false;
}else if(!ck_password.test(fpassword)){
document.form.password.focus();
document.getElementById("elmepasswordError").innerHTML="Enter the Password with 6-20 characters";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmepasswordError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if( fconpassword=="")
{
document.form.confirmpassword.focus();
document.getElementById("elmeconfirmpasswordError").innerHTML="Enter the Confirm Password";
return false;
}else if(!ck_password.test( fconpassword)){
document.form.confirmpassword.focus();
document.getElementById("elmeconfirmpasswordError").innerHTML="Should match with Password";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmeconfirmpasswordError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(fconpassword != fpassword )
{

document.form.confirmpassword.focus();
document.getElementById("elmere-enterpasswordError").innerHTML="Passwords are not matching,re-enter again";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmere-enterpasswordError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(fmonth=="")
{
document.form.birthday_month.focus();
document.getElementById("elmebirthday_monthError").innerHTML="Select the Birthday of Month";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmebirthday_monthError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(fday=="")
{
document.form.birthday_day.focus();
document.getElementById("elmebirthday_dayError").innerHTML="Select the Birthday of Day";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmebirthday_dayError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(fyear=="")
{
document.form.birthday_year.focus();
document.getElementById("elmebirthday_yearError").innerHTML="Select the Birthday of Year";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmebirthday_yearError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(document.form.radiobutton[0].checked==false && document.form.radiobutton[1].checked == false){
document.getElementById("elmeGenderError").innerHTML="Select Your Gender";
return false;
}else {
document.getElementById("elmeGenderError").innerHTML=" ";
}

if(fname!='' && lname!='' && femail!='' && fuser!='' &&  fpassword!='' && fconpassword!='' && fmonth!='' && fday!='' && fyear!=''){

location.href="Useraccountpage.htm";
return false;
}

}


function Cancel(){
window.location="Loginpage.htm";
return false;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Holder">
<!----------Header---------->
<div id="Header">
</div>

<!----------NAVBAR---------->
        <div id="NavBar">
        <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="Registrationpage.htm">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href ="Useraccountpage.htm"></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
<div id="Content">

<div id="PageHeading">

</div>

<div id="ContentLeft">

<br>
</div>

<div id="ContentRight">
    <section class="loginform cf">
    <form name="form"  action="Useraccountpage.htm"  method="post"  id="form_id">

    <table class="center">

        <tr>
          <td><label for="first-name">First Name</label></td>

         <td><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></td>  
            </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

           <tr >
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="styletxtfields" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName">
            </td>   
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="styletxtfields" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName">
        </td>
      </tr>

        <tr><td id="elmfirstnameError" colspan="2" class="errorMsg" ></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="elmlastnameError" colspan="2"  class="errorMsg" >&nbsp;</td></tr>


      <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="email">Email Id</label>
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="email" class="styletxtfields" name="email" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter the Email ID">
        </td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td id="elmemailError"  colspan="2" class="errorMsg" >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>




    <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="user">User Name</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="styletxtfields" name="username" placeholder="UserName">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="elmeusernameError" colspan="2" class="errorMsg">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td><label for="password" >Password</label></td><br>
        <td><label for="password" >Confirm Password</label></td><br>
        </tr>

        <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
            <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="password" class="styletxtfields" name="password" placeholder="Enter the Password">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="password"  class="styletxtfields" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Enter the Conform Password">
        </td>
            </tr>


        <tr><td id="elmepasswordError" colspan="2" class="errorMsg"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="elmeconfirmpasswordError"  class="errorMsg"></td></tr>

        <tr>
        <th id="elmere-enterpasswordError" colspan="2" class="errorMsg">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="DOB">Date of Birthday</label>
        </td>
    <td>
      <select name="birthday_month"  class="styleselfield">
          <option value="" selected >Month</option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option>
          <option value="2">Feb</option>
          <option value="3">Mar</option>
          <option value="4">Apr</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
          <option value="6">Jun</option>
          <option value="7">Jul</option>
          <option value="8">Aug</option>
          <option value="9">Sep</option>
          <option value="10">Oct</option>
          <option value="11">Nov</option>
          <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="birthday_day" class="styleselfield" >
          <option value="" selected>Day</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="21">21</option>
          <option value="22">22</option>
          <option value="23">23</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="26">26</option>
          <option value="27">27</option>
          <option value="28">28</option>
          <option value="29">29</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="birthday_year" class="styleselfield">
          <option value="" selected>Year</option>
          <option value="2013">2013</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
          <option value="2011">2011</option>
          <option value="2010">2010</option>
          <option value="2009">2009</option>
          <option value="2008">2008</option>
          <option value="2007">2007</option>
          <option value="2006">2006</option>
          <option value="2005">2005</option>
          <option value="2004">2004</option>
          <option value="2003">2003</option>
          <option value="2002">2002</option>
          <option value="2001">2001</option>
          <option value="2000">2000</option>
          <option value="1999">1999</option>
          <option value="1998">1998</option>
          <option value="1997">1997</option>
          <option value="1996">1996</option>
          <option value="1995">1995</option>
          <option value="1994">1994</option>
          <option value="1993">1993</option>
          <option value="1992">1992</option>
          <option value="1991">1991</option>
          <option value="1990">1990</option>
        </select>

    </td>
    </tr>

        <tr><td id="elmebirthday_monthError" class="errorMsg"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="elmebirthday_dayError" class="errorMsg"></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="elmebirthday_yearError"   class="errorMsg">&nbsp;</td></tr>





    <tr>
        <td>
                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
        <label>Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
        <label>Female</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="elmeGenderError" class="errorMsg">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>

    <tr>
        <td  style="text-align:center">
        <input type="button"   value="Register" onClick="Submit()" ><br>

        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
        <input type="button" onClick="Cancel()"  value="Cancel">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</section>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Page 2 where I want data from from Page 1 and display using cookies in javascript:

```
    Page 2 :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UFT-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue(varname)
{  var url = window.location.href;   

   var qparts = url.split("?");       

  if (qparts.length == 0)             
  {
    return "";
  }

   var query = qparts[1];               

   var vars = query.split("&");         

   var value = "";                        

    for (i=0;i<vars.length;i++)              
  {
        var parts = vars[i].split("=");       
        if (parts[0] == varname)               
    {
      value = parts[1];                
      break;                                 
    }
  }
  value = unescape(value);             
  value.replace(/\+/g," ");             
  return value;                        
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
<nav>
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="Content">
<div id="PageHeading">
<h1>WELCOME TO USER ACCOUNT</h1>
</div>
<div id="ContentLeft">
<h2>Your Message Here</h2><br>
<br>
<h6>
Your Message</h6>
</div>
 <div id="ContentRight">
<form onload="getValue(varname)">
<table align="center">
<tr>
   <td> First Name</td>
   <td><Label id="sfName"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> LastName :</td>
   <td><Label id="slName"></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Email</td>
   <td><Label id="semail"></Label></td>
</tr>
<tabel>
</form>
<script>
var fname=getValue("firstname");
var lname=getValue("lastname");
var email = getValue("email");

document.getElementById("sfName").innerHTML= fname;
document.getElementById("slName").innerHTML= lname;
document.getElementById("semail").innerHTML= email;
</script>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual question you're asking? If the pages are on the same domain you might try using localStorage or sessionStorage to share data.

Comment: I am trying to show details on page 2 from page 1 using cookies set -cookies and get-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are persistent, automatically included in every get/post, and not a best choice for what you seem to be trying to accomplish.

The post in your example won't be sharing via the href property.  Form posts send data to a server.  The HTM output won't see that data directly.

The best option is to process the submitted data on a server, preferably over https.  Server side scripting languages receive the data and can be used to update a database.  For example, in Lucee a structure called FORM is populated, in php a named array called $_POST is populated.

Failing that, if the data needs to be browser persistent, store it in localStorage or sessionStorage.  If it only needs to be passed between pages, do the same; but, delete the entries upon consumption.

page 1:

```
<input name="firstname" onchange="localStorage.firstName=this.value;">
```

page 2:

```
document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML=localStorage.firstName;
// - if not persistent: localStorage.removeItem("firstName");
```

Comment: sorry I am not getting what are you trying to say ? 
I want to show the data which have entering on page1, should display on page2 using cookies where I have written "getValue(varname)" method in page 2 to get the data form page 1 .

Comment: If all your trying to do is understand cookies, the thing to remember is setting `document.cookie="firstName=John"` adds a cookie, and getting `myCookieArray=document.cookie.split(';')` returns an array with all the cookies in it. If you want an object with all the values, loop through the array and `a=split('=')` each element `a[0]` is the name `a[1]` is the value.

Comment: But if your purpose is storage of names and passwords DON'T DO IT. This is security 101.  Cookies are visible to everyone.  Also, cookies typically have about a 2kb upper limit for combined storage.